# Belize repatriation fee with valid US visa

Tags: belize

Has anyone one with an Indian (or China, Pakistan, Bangladesh, Sri Lanka) passport and a valid US visa been to Belize? If so, I would like to know if they had to pay the $1200 BZD ($600 USD) [repatriation fees](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=BZ&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) while entering. The consulate website [here](http://www.embassyofbelize.gov.bz/consular-services/obtaining-a-visa.html) states there is no fee for valid US visa holders. So the information is contradictory and the Belize embassy in US is not responsive.

Comment: This is likely to be closed, per @pnuts link. If you have a multiple-entry US visa, it would be better to directly query the [Embassy of Belize](http://www.embassyofbelize.gov.bz/contact-us.html) directly.

Comment: I did ask the embassy but they did not respond, hence, I was asking if anyone has had first hand experience. The repatriation fee also applies to nationals of China, Pakistan, Sri Lanka and Bangladesh. So my question is relevant to half the population of this earth.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any indication that the repatriation fee is waived for US visa holders. That's quite expensive, insultingly so, but I don't see anything that says the fee doesn't apply.

Comment: @ZachLipton it does show that _Visa required, except for Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by the USA can obtain a visa on arrival._ And, sadly Belize had a history of being a jumping-off point for illegal entry into the US with the result being the heavy 'fee.'

Comment: There is a [reference](http://rapidtravelchai.boardingarea.com/2011/11/03/2000-for-a-visa-sorry-honey-maybe-next-time/) to the repatriation fee being refundable upon exit, but seeing as that is the only reference I can find to that being the case, you may want to seek additional confirmation of this being true.

Comment: Hello @Mohit, I'm traveling to Belize with a US multiple Entry Visa. Shocked to see the repatriation fee of BZD1200. Did you travel to Belize? Did you pay the fees and was it refunded on exit?

Comment: I personally did not end up travelling to Belize. However, I know someone who was able to travel on a US Visa and India Passport by just paying the $50 Visa fee on arrival. This was back in 2015, so you might want to confirm with someone who's traveled more recently.